# Creating a model for a drag racing car

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We would like to create a model for a drag racing car. The horizontal distance of the car from the start line is given by x(t) and is measured in meters. Therefore the speed of the car is given by dx/dt and the acceleration is given by d^2x/dt^2.

We make the following assumptions about the motion of the car:

1) The car has an acceleration of 10 m/s^2;

2) The car starts from rest

3) The car starts at the start line

4) The car travels in a straight line

(a) Write down an initial value problem that models the motion of the car. Be sure to include all initial conditions. You do not need to solve the initial value problem.

I do not understand how to create a modelling equation for this question, any helpers?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple question. Just keep in mind,(if you have pre-knowledge; if you don't, just consult a textbook on high-school Physics) the Equations of motion in a straight line.

(i) x(t) = x(initial) + v(initial).t + (1/2).a.(t^2)

(ii) v(final) =  v(initial) + a.t

(iii) (v(final))^2 = (v(initial))^2 + 2.a.x(t)

from conditions given, according to the order mentioned in question, we get,

1) a = 10 (a is not a function of t, and is constant. That's why the above equations hold)

2) v(initial) = 0

3) x(initial) = 0

4) We have already made use of this assumption in calling in the equations above.

putting all values, our equations condense to:

(i) x(t) =  5.(t^2)

(ii) v(final) =  10.t

(iii) (v(final))^2 =  20.x(t)

I guess you can now frame the modelling equation on your own, on the basis of these last 3 equations.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I already had prior knowledge of these equations yet I would not have guessed they would tie into a modelling question. Out of interest what would be a modelling equation you would suggest to answer this question?

Comment: I would rather mix all 3 into (v(final))^2 = 10.x(t) + 50.(t^2); but I find it rather odd.